# html5 video: fastest fast forward and slowest slow motion?

Tags: html, html5-video

Wondering what the bounds are for variable rate playback with html5 video.

I seem to min and max out playing with this demo:
http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

I've done a cursory glance at the [specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-playbackrate), but don't see anything there.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this on different computers cpu powers, and found that there is no upper limit. However, the fastest effective speed will be dependent on your cpu power. I got 15x maximum speed on corei7 -4770k @3.5Ghz and got around 10x on less powered haswell corei5 @2.5Ghz.

These are the chrome extensions used for changing the speed: 
[chrome extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk?hl=en)

[another chrome extension with modifiable hotkeys (but it needs to be added to chrome by loading an unpacked extension)](https://github.com/ricardobcl/HTML5-Speedy-Video-Extension)

**Update**:

Here is something related to Internet Explorer:

> The `playbackRate` property represents a multiplier of the video's intrinsic or normal playback rate, with the default setting of 1. If you set the property to 2, it doubles the playback speed, while .5 will play at half speed. If `playbackRate` is set to a negative value, in Windows Internet Explorer 9, it rounds it back to zero, essentially pausing playback. In Internet Explorer 10, negative values for `playbackRate` cause the video to play in reverse. **The W3C spec doesn't recommend an upper limit**, but Internet Explorer limits `playbackRate` up to 8x speed.

Source: [Using JavaScript to control the HTML5 video player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh924823(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

GPU acceleration helps to achieve even more.

Beside the chrome's extension for playback speed , I use [enounce myspeed](http://www.enounce.com/myspeed).
It helps to achieve more speeds when turning up the enounce myspeed to the maximum 5x and increasing the chrome extension's html5 video playback speed.

I got 30-40x maximum speed (total of 5x of myspeed * 6x to 8x of the chrome extension) for Full HD video on corei7 -3770k @3.5Ghz with Nvidia GTX 1080 Ti. Pascal GPUs support h264 or h265 or even VP9 codecs (which used in youtube videos).

The video that was tested:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSZw8egM2Is

Video Engine of the GPU was most of the time more than 90% utilization and the download of buffering from internet was not enough with my 100Mbit bandwidth, so still the youtube sometimes rarely with these speeds stops a bit, and anything more than this speed the stopping for buffering will become more frequent either due to depleted buffering or sometimes even with the buffering still available but maybe due to the more than 90% video engine utilization.

TDP was 35% of GPU.

When I switched the resolution to 480p, it gave me 75x , although buffering is good and video engine is 50% but could not increase the speed more due to the frequent stopping with the buffering circles icons rotating)

In my Surface pro3 that has no GPU accelaration other than the builtin Haswell GPU: I got 20x maximum smooth playback if combined with myspeed for 480p.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>I was looking for this myself, and happened upon your question. You probably want to do that with a canvas, by keeping a queue of frames. Unfortunately, that solution only works for the video, not the audio. You can see an example here:</strike>

http://techslides.com/demos/slow-motion.html

I'm still looking for information on how to slow the audio.

EDIT:

There's a way easier solution - [the playbackrate property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_playbackrate.asp).

Comment: yes, I reference that property in my post.  my question is: what is the slowest and what is the fastest playback rate?

Answer (score -2):

Playbackspeed divided to following. You can break bring down the speed to 0.1 slowest and 2.0 the fastest i guess;

1. 1.0 is normal speed
2. 0.5 is half speed (slower)
3. 2.0 is double speed (faster)
4. -1.0 is backwards, normal speed
5. -0.5 is backwards, half speed

Here is [demo at w3schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_playbackrate). You can find further while playing  `vid.playbackRate = 0.5;` value.

Full read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_playbackrate.asp).